# JQuery Mobile Phone gap: Split view using asyraf9 example not working

Tags: jquery, android, iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to implement a split view using jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap in iPad. Many sites recommended asyraf9's https://github.com/asyraf9/jquery-mobile/

I have downloaded the zip file it has bundle of files in it. In the folder `demos\experiments\` I saw the a "splitview" directory. I used the contents of that dir for reference.

I have added all the files used the files from the split view folder in my `www` folder. It shows only a view as shown bellow but not the split view

And some part of code in index.htms is changes as shown bellow when we used " &copy CS8 "

any syntax prob in " &copy CS8 "

[image]

among the which file is to be used as plug in for the split view..?

When i used it's split views index.html file it does not shows split view

it just like a segment vies with table views but not split view

[image]
whats wrong

Answer (score 3):

To make it work for splitsview.. In the Splitsview.js file make

```
$.support.splitview =($query || ($.mobile.browser.ie && $(this).width() >= 480)) 
                      && $.mobile.ajaxEnabled;
```

as(comment the right hand side and do $.support.splitview = 1;)

```
$.support.splitview = 1;//($query || ($.mobile.browser.ie && $(this).width() >= 480)) 
                           && $.mobile.ajaxEnabled;
```

Then spliview will work for any phone whatever its size may be.

Answer (score 1):

Did You mean 'data-id="menu"' ?. In fact, it works well in a web browser on desktop, the problem appears only when I build it with PhoneGap to have an app on Android.
Here is my index.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
        <title>Jquery Mobile Splitview</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.splitview.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/jquery.mobile.grids.collapsible.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile.splitview.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/iscroll-wrapper.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/iscroll.js"></script>
    <!--script type="text/javascript" src="scrollability.js"></script-->        
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="panel" data-id="menu" data-hash="crumbs" data-context="a#default">
        <!-- Start of main page -->
        <div data-role="page" id="main" data-hash="false">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Left panel</h1>
            </div><!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content">
                The left content
            </div><!-- /content -->
        </div><!-- /page -->
    </div><!-- panel menu -->

    <div data-role="panel" data-id="main">
        <!-- Start of about page -->
        <div data-role="page" id="about">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Right panel</h1>
            </div><!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content">
                The right content
            </div><!-- /content -->
        </div><!-- /page -->
    </div><!-- panel main -->
    </body>
 </html>
```

It seems PhoneGap doesn't support this plugin.

Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

In the index.html, check out you have two divs, one having data-role="menu" and another data-role="main".  So, once you have it, in the portrait mode you have the main page getting displayed.  In the landscape mode, you have the menu and main page getting displayed.

Can you check by removing the &copy code, to verify that in the absence of the same, will you be able to get the split view.